# Websockets no longer work for me at all

Tags: javascript, websocket, leap-motion

I've been programming alot for the Leap Motion lately, writing javascript web apps for it.  The Leap sends data through a websocket that you can receive in the browser.  I've been using it no problem for months.  All of a sudden I can't get data from it through the websocket.  I uninstalled and re-installed the software, tried with a different device, tried different versions of their software, restart the computer many times and nothing helps.  All the software works fine for everyone else I know with a Leap and it works fine on my other computer.  It happens in firefox, chrome, and nodewebkit.  It happens for stuff hosted on my server, my desktop, and other peoples servers. I'm on win7.

Now I am thinking that there is something messing with the websocket connection that isn't in their software, some setting or problem on my machine.  I've tried using websocket demos I googled for and they don't seem to work either.

I went to http://websocketstest.com/ and I get disconnected on port 80, 443, and 8080, but it works on 443 with SSL.

What could it be?

Comment: Sure it isn't a hardware problem with the Leap? Does it still work with native apps?

Comment: Check your [Firewall settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall), as [websocketstest.com](http://websocketstest.com/) is failing on all browsers it would seem that outbound traffic (you ability to connect as client on those ports) is blocked.

Comment: FWIW: the Leap Motion websocket server uses port 6437.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being some anti virus software I installed blocking it.